# Maximum in group by active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, max

I have a Model which has two attributes (I am showing only two as only those two columns are needed)

MyModel

---

place_id  ------------------------ user_id

1 ----------------------------------   1

1 ----------------------------------   2

1 ----------------------------------   2

3 ----------------------------------   3

3 ----------------------------------   2

3 ----------------------------------   3

3 ----------------------------------   1

I want to fetch group by maximum records. Basically I want to fetch for a particular place which user has maximum records like for for place_id 1 user 2 has maximum results and for place 3 user 3 has maximum results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are specifying a place first you can do:

```
MyModel.where("place_id=?",place_id).
        group("place_id,user_id").order("count(user_id) DESC").first
```

If you want to get all the maximums at once, then remove the where clause and iterate through your result set, taking only the first record for each distinct place_id.  Or you may be able to add a distinct to the statement above.  Something like this?

```
MyModel.select("DISTINCT(place_id)").
        merge(MyModel.group("place_id,user_id").order("count(user_id) DESC"))
```

Good luck!