# rails activerecord order in group

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to display the latest version(**version is float: 1, 1.1, 1.2...**) in every result group.
here is my code:

```
@results = Result.where(project_id: @project_id).group(:result_id).order("result_version DESC")
```

and in rails server message:

```
SELECT  `results`.* FROM `results` WHERE `results`.`project_id` = 2 GROUP BY `results`.`result_id`  ORDER BY result_version DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

but it's not work, so I try **ASC**:

```
@results = Result.where(project_id: @project_id).group(:result_id).order(:result_version)
```

message:

```
SELECT  `results`.* FROM `results` WHERE `results`.`project_id` = 2 GROUP BY `results`.`result_id`  ORDER BY `results`.`result_version` ASC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

in view, two method show the same thing(**order by ASC**).
how can I do order in the group?

data like this:

```
id, project_id, result_version, result_id, result_num
'6',   '2',          '1',         '1',     'N00009999000010'
'7',   '2',          '1',         '2',     ‘N00009999000020'
'8',   '2',          '1',         '3',     'N00009999000030'
'10',  '2',          '1.1',       '2',     'N00009999000020'
'11',  '2',          '1.1',       '3',     'N00009999000030'
```

P.S. if simply use .order(result_version: :desc), it work.
my problem just like this issue:
[Maximum in group by active record query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468316/maximum-in-group-by-active-record-query)
but it's answer can't solve my problem.

Comment: Is there really a `results.result_id` ?

Comment: yes.I add comment for data.

Comment: There's something wrong with with your data : if you really group by `results.result_id` (which is confusing btw) result_id should be uniq. Also when you group by a value the other values of the table aren't (usually) available ((only for the aggregate function)....  So you're probably sorting for an absent value....

Comment: It just a test DB, result_id is just a name for group(not use in normal id), so it can be uniq. and my result_version and result_id are all exist.

Comment: I think you're confusing `.group` which generates a SQL statement and `.group_by` which is a ruby method that creates sub-groups of a given array of objects. You cannot "order in a group" from a SQL result since the rows of each result_id value is "compressed" in a single row.

Comment: oh...very precise, thanks a lot! so how can I do? is there no way to solve may problem?

Comment: see my answer & tell me if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in my comment you should be using group_by instead of group.
The result you're looking for might look like this :

```
Result.where(project_id: @project_id).
       order(result_version: asc).
       group_by {|result| result.result_id}
```

This will generate a hash that looks something like that :

`{5: [result1, result2], 6: [result7, result8]}`

You can then iterate over it in your view as such

```
 - @grouped_result.each do |result_id, array_of_results|
   Result ID: 
   = result_id
   - array_of_results.each do |result|
     = result.result_num
     = result.result_version
     # etc....
```

Comment: the hash just like what you say, but if I only want the latest version shows in view, what can I add in the "- array_of_results.each do |result|"? because of the array already sorting, I only need first record, does any simply way to achive?

Comment: I use a stupid way:
<% @results.each do |result_id, array| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= array[0].data %></td>
          ...
        </tr>


use array[0] to read first record, so  there is no need double loop, does any other simply way?

Comment: Not really but for readability you can set a variable instead of calling [0] for each attribute. `- first_result = array[0]` and then `first_result.data` etc

Answer (score 0):

The first is calling the column wrong:

```
@results = Result.where(project_id: @project_id).group(:result_id).order(:result_version => :desc)
```

UPDATE: do you have a default scope? In that case use reorder method instead of order.

Comment: still get data order by ASC.

Comment: no use any default scope in result model, by the way, I just try reorder method and still same output...

Comment: Also the other declaration I suggested? `order(:result_version => :desc)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Result.where('project_id = ?', @project_id).group('result_id').order('result_version desc')
```

Use sort_by instead of order:-

```
Result.where('project_id = ?', @project_id).group('result_id').sort_by(&:result_version)
```

Updated :-

```
Result.where('project_id = ?', @project_id).sort_by(&:result_version).group_by('result_id')
```